# How to import a WPF DLL (C#) in C/C++?

Tags: c#, c++, .net, wpf, xaml

I want to get access to an external WPF window in my application (has to be C/C++). I am fairly new to this, but as far as I know I have to put all the functions in a DLL and import them in my code. Unfortunately I get stuck when it comes to the linking between the DLL and my code. I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015 and I created one project of type *wpf control library* and another project of type *console application* (only for testing) and linked them together in one solution as described in [this walkthrough](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms235636.aspx). Here is what I have so far:

**UserControl1.xaml.cs:**

```
using RGiesecke.DllExport;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace WpfControlLibrary1
{
    class Control
    {
        [DllExport("AddInteger", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static int AddInteger(int Value1, int Value2)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show("Add Integers: " + Value1.ToString() + " " + Value2.ToString(), "AddInteger");
            return (Value1 + Value2);
        }
    }
}
```

**ConsoleApplication1.cpp:**

```
// ConsoleApplication1.cpp
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>

int main()
{
    typedef int(*AI)(int val1, int val2);

    HMODULE DLL = LoadLibrary(_T("WpfControlLibrary1.dll"));

    if (DLL)
    {
        std::cout << "DLL loaded!" << std::endl;
        AI AddInteger = (AI)GetProcAddress(DLL, "AddInteger");

        //int res = AddInteger(1, 2);
        std::cout << AddInteger << std::endl;

        if (AddInteger)
        {
            std::cout << "Successful link to function in DLL!" << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Unable to link to function in DLL!" << std::endl;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "DLL failed to load!" << std::endl;
    }
    FreeLibrary(DLL);
    return 0;
}
```

The first message “DLL loaded!” is written to the console so the library seems to load fine (?). But when I call the AddInteger function the console crashes. (The function pointer is 0).
Are the projects types correct or am I using them in a wrong way? Visual Studio originally created something like this for the UserControl1.xaml.cs:

```
namespace WpfControlLibrary1
{
    public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
    {
        public UserControl1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

I changed it as you can see above.
What am I doing wrong here? Please light me up. Thank you vm.

Comment: You probably should use C++/CLI to write the glue code between C# and C++. `DllExportAttribute` is a third-party hack.

Comment: Link to a introduction to [C++/cli](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/68td296t.aspx) (Here is a [German version](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/68td296t.aspx), as your original link was to the German MSDN)

Comment: If it is at _all_ possible, pull in C++/CLI for interop scenarios like this. You can do this from a fully C++ project by creating a shim library in C++/CLI.  Seriously. It will save you a _lot_ of pain.

Comment: Your function pointer declaration is not correct, it is __cdecl, not __stdcall as your C# code requires.  COM is a good way to do this in a type-safe way.